# Adding a database ID to an Eclipse Combo

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, combobox

I'm working on a Java application in Eclipse that pulls data out of a MySQL database. I'm populating a combo box with data. So far I can get the value of a field to show up but I can't figure out how to store the database row's unique ID value. One suggestion I found was to create a custom class that could store both the display value and the id value. However, this doesn't appear to work with the Eclipse widget combo object.  This is what I have

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;

class myClass {
   public static void createCombo(ResultSet rs) {
      Combo c = new Combo();
      while(rs.next()) {
         int id = rs.getInt("id");
         int display = rs.getString("display");
         comboitem ci = new comboitem(id,display);
         c.add(ci);
      }
   }
}
class comboitem {
   private int _id;
   private String _display;

   public comboitem(int id, String display) {
     this._id = id;
     this._display = display;
   }
   public int getID(){
      return _id;
   }
   public String toString(){
     return _display;
    }
}
```

The above errors at c.add(ci). It's expecting a string, not an object. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No idea but, I've always felt it was a bad move anyway.
Create a collection/list of comboitems, populate the widget from comboitem.display.
Index in the combo is index in your collection.
Means you can unit test lots of things without a UI or with simple mock, and it keeps you away from desktop specific implementations in your data models.

Answer (score 0):

The combo widget displays an array of String's, so simply concatenate the two values if you want to display them both.  I am not sure what your end goal is from your question.  If it is to select the appropriate comboitem based on the combo selection, then store the comboitems in a Map and use the combo values as the keys.

Another approach is to use a jface ComboViewer which allows you to set the input to a complex object, provide a label provider and more complex controls around the Combo widget.

You should also look up some information on java coding conventions and not access your database directly from the UI unless this is a very simple application.

You can find some examples on using most SWT widgets [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/0220__Combo.htm).